# Forgot nextcloud root password which I have setup in localhost with Ubuntu LAMP stack

Tags: root, lamp, ubuntu-18.04, forgot-password, nextcloud

I have set up LAMP stack in my local Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. MariaDB root password is working fine.

I have setup nextcloud in my localhost. Non root user password is working fine. But I have forgot root login password.

How to reset it.

Comment: Not sure what you refer to by "root account" inside a nextcloud installation. Probably you refer to some user account having global admininstration rights... You can setup a new nextcloud instance and then overwrite the hashed password in the database. I doubt there is another option. But that won't work with server side encryption enabled, I am afraid, you'd lose that account's data.

Comment: OK I am just learning nextcloud, and have no data, how to do a fresh installation?

Comment: @arkascha There is another option as I described in my answer below.

Comment: @SurfMan That is interesting, didn't know that one. Unfortunately the `occ` command is an ever changing thingy, one never knows what it currently offers ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nextcloud has a document for that (https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/9/admin_manual/configuration_user/reset_admin_password.html). What happened when you tried that?

From the documentation:

> That is using the occ command. occ is in the nextcloud directory, for example /var/www/nextcloud/occ. occ has a command for resetting all user passwords, user:resetpassword. It is best to run occ as the HTTP user, as in this example on Ubuntu Linux:

```
$ sudo -u www-data php /var/www/nextcloud/occ user:resetpassword admin
Enter a new password:
Confirm the new password:
Successfully reset password for admin
```

> If your Nextcloud username is not admin, then substitute your Nextcloud username.

If you are using docker, use the following (note: requires 10 characters for the new password)

```
$ docker exec -it -u www-data <<containername>> php /var/www/html/occ user:resetpassword admin
```

Comment: Could not sent reset email because  there is no email addres provided for the user please contact server administrator.

Comment: Read further than the first sentence. There is a third option, and that is using the occ command.

Comment: Could not open input file: /var/www/nextcloud/occ

Comment: Is that the exact location where you installed NextCloud? You you have permissions? Does the www-data user exist? Does that have permissions?

Comment: no it is /var/www/html/nextcloud/occ, don't know why it is coming like this

Comment: So the command would be `sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/nextcloud/occ user:resetpassword admin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179730/discussion-between-suraj-and-surfman).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered NextCloud thanks to softaculous on an inexpensive DirectAdmin managed server I got on impulse. It came **without shell access** (ugh).

Admin password quit working ( that's my story and I'm sticking to it )!

I can set cron jobs and see the results via email... so to set a new admin password I entered the following cron job  to run a minute away:

```
export OC_PASS=my_not_simple_password_or_it_will_be_denied157; php /home/my_server_account/public_html/cloud/occ user:resetpassword --password-from-env admin
```

Hope it helps someone else.